# How to bind Height to parent's height minus another item's height

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox that is showing an Image and a Text above it. I have bound the DataTemplate to a custom MyImage class that has a String `Str` and an Image `Image`. The next Image would appear right of the first one since the surrounding StackPanel is Horizontal.

I have problems getting the Height of the Image to a value where it would fill the entire ListBox's Height minus the Text's Height and Margin.
In the code below I have bound it to the ActualHeight of the ListBox `listboxMyImages`. 
I would like to be able to substract now the Height of the TextBlock from that value. What's the best way to do that?

[image]

```
<ListBox x:Name="listboxMyImages"  Margin="10,10,10,10">
                                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyImage}">
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblMyImage" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Str}" />
                                                    <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding Image}"  Height="{Binding ElementName=listboxMyImages, Path=ActualHeight }"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

use another Panel - `Grid` with 2 rows

```
<Grid>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TextBlock x:Name="lblMyImage" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Str}" />
<Image Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Source="{Binding Image}"/>

</Grid>
```

image will stretch and take all available Height

Comment: That actually stretches the image to its original size and makes me scroll down in the ListBox.

Comment: It seems that itemspanel StackPanel allows non-limited height for items. I need to think about improvement

Comment: Okay, thanks! Let me know when you thought of  something.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a StackPanel you could try to use a Grid like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Not sure if it works as I cannot try it right now.